# How to start apache2 automatically in a ubuntu docker container?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a Dockerfile that will start apache automatically. Nothing has worked. But If I log into the container and run `service apache2 start` it works. Why can I not run that command from my Dockerfile?

```
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER rmuktader

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

# Install and run apache
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-k", "start"]


#ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
#ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
#ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
CMD service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The issue is here: `CMD service apache2 start` When you execute this command process `apache2` will be detached from the shell. But Docker works only while main process is alive.

The solution is to run Apache in the **foreground**. `Dockerfile` must look like this: (only last line changed).

```
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER rmuktader

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

# Install and run apache
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-k", "start"]


#ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
#ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
#ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Comment: it did not work. I copied and pasted your Dockerfile, ran `docker build -t my_img .`, ran `docker run -ti -p80:80 --name 'test2' my_img /bin/bash` but apache was not running.

Comment: i tried this approach and it works for me. Try to remove `/bin/bash` from your command

Comment: If you try to run multiple services in one container it will not work. Docker way is one container for one service.Please explain your issue and i will try to help you to solve it with docker true way.

Comment: I'm trying to pull down a live installation of redmine 1.3 from a production a server and run it on my local machine with docker. I need to have the same version of everything. I did not expect it to be this tough. Maybe docker isn't the right solution for something like this.

Comment: This worked for me, after hours of toiling over other things that most definitely did not work. Thank you, @BukharovSergey!!! A thousand internet points to you today.

Comment: What does `-D` mean? I cannot find in [apachectl documentation](https://documentation.help/httpd-2.4/apachectl.html)

Comment: @ikhvjs That doc shows `apachectl [ httpd-argument ]` and explains that "When acting in pass-through mode, apachectl can take all the arguments available for the httpd binary". That one references the `-D parameter` option and says: "Sets a configuration parameter which can be used with <IfDefine> sections in the configuration files to conditionally skip or process commands at server startup and restart. Also can be used to set certain less-common startup parameters including -DNO_DETACH (prevent the parent from forking) and -DFOREGROUND (prevent the parent from calling setsid() et al)."

Comment: @Ethan, thanks for your comment. I also found the documentation from the [next page](https://documentation.help/httpd-2.4/apxs.html)

Answer (score 28):

For me last line with CMD was wrong:

```
# it helped me
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 8):

My project was slightly different where I installed a bunch of other stuff, but the apache start portion matched above.  Once I built this image and used it, my server started fine.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#install all the tools you might want to use in your container
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y
#the following ARG turns off the questions normally asked for location and timezone for Apache
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y

#change working directory to root of apache webhost
WORKDIR var/www/html

#copy your files, if you want to copy all use COPY . .
COPY index.html index.html

#now start the server
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive no ask anyone option?

Answer (score 4):

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt install apache2 -y && apt-get clean

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apachectl", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

Adding the `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
ADD index.html /var/www/html
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple docker file for run ubuntu with apache server

```
RUN apt-get update
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  # for remove time zone
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
ADD . /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT apachectl -D FOREGROUND
ENV name Vishal                   # anything you can give
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: None of the above commands provided worked for me on `Docker version 24.0.5`, like, 

`CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND`

`CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]`


But ENTRYPOINT worked.

`ENTRYPOINT apachectl -D FOREGROUND`