# Cant get apache2 started in docker container

Tags: docker, apache2

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","start"]
```

But when I build image and run the container, I check apache status and get:

```
root@79074bf56be4:/# service apache2 status
 * apache2 is not running
```

And if I start it manually inside the container, it works:

```
root@79074bf56be4:/# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl start
root@79074bf56be4:/#
root@79074bf56be4:/# service apache2 status
 * apache2 is running
root@79074bf56be4:/#
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make the apache2 start automatically on container start?

Comment: What is the command that you are using to start the container?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I didn't google good

[Here is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376852/how-to-start-apache2-automatically-in-a-ubuntu-docker-container)

Solved by replacing CMD line to this:

```
CMD apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

And cuntainer run command to this:

```
docker run --detach my_image
```