# Creating a custom docker container to match my server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to docker, needed to use it for a legacy project that requires php5. Here is my `Dockerfile` snippet:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.1
LABEL MAINTAINER Hasan
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-server php5-mysql && \
    apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD service apache2 start
```

Here is the command to build it:

```
docker build -t rakibtg/oldapp .
```

It gives few error including 'Hash Sum mismatch' and 'returned a non-zero code: 100'

> Fetched 16.7 MB in 60s (274 kB/s)
>   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-modules_5.18.2-2ubuntu1.4_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
>   The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y apache2 &&     apt-get install -y mysql-server php5-mysql &&     apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt' returned a non-zero code: 100

What should i do to fix it? 
Also, is the `CMD` is configured properly here? Any guide would be appreciated

- I am using docker on mac

Answer (score 1):

This error seems more linked to `apt-get` behavior rather than to Docker. 
You can try:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.1
LABEL MAINTAINER Hasan
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-server php5-mysql && \
    apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

or other solutions mentioned in [Troube downloading packages list due to a hash sum mismatch error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

By the way I changed your CMD statement. Indeed when using service the process will be detached from shell and Docker will stop the container (See [How to start apache2 automatically in a ubuntu docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376852/how-to-start-apache2-automatically-in-a-ubuntu-docker-container) for associated explanations)