# Prevent apache2 / http2 from running as daemon for Docker container?

Tags: apache, docker, apache2, daemon, docker-run

I have this at the end of Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT service apache2 start
```

I get this logged:

```
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
```

and then my container will exit - it shouldn't be an error, I just think the container exits because the process is a daemon. Is there a way to keep it open?

Comment: Please see the correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377561/609290

Comment: ah thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start apache2 automatically in a ubuntu docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376852/how-to-start-apache2-automatically-in-a-ubuntu-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

So I can keep the container alive with:

```
ENTRYPOINT service apache2 restart && /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

---

but I don't know how to get the stdout/stderr from Apache to stdout/stderr of the Docker container, anybody know? I can confirm apache is running if I keep the container alive.

I found this example too:

```
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
```

but I can't find the path to my apache2 executable.

Answer (score 0):

So this should be the correct answer:

```
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["apachectl"]
```

that is, if you installed apache with:

```
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
```